# How would I correct the pyramid traversal as it is not working correctly?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, while-loop

This is the error I get when I ran the code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ian/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/pyramid.py", line 95, in 
    elif random_roll == 2  and (pd[y][x]) != 3 \
IndexError: list index out of range

The error changes every time I run the program because it follows a different path ( or it's supposed to). I have four directions that I am trying to go up left, up right, down left, downright from each node in PD, if There isn't a node in the randomized direction I log it and try again till I find the proper direction to go. I have issues when going DL from 2 it will go to 6 instead of 5 and UR from 9 will give an out of bounds error. I have spent several hours playing around with the coordinates yet to no avail. Would someone please assist me as I am unable to understand why it's going out of bounds.

```
import random


pd = [ #This is the visual of the pyramid

[                 1                    ], #[0][0]  row and total col# ex [2][1] = 5
[              2,    3                 ], #[1][1]
[            4,   5,    6,             ], #[2][2]
[         7,   8,    9,   10,          ], #[3][3]
[      11,  12,   13,  14,   15,       ], #[4][4]
[    16,  17,   18,  19,  20,    21,   ], #[5][5]

]


dots_list = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21]]
'''

dots_list[0].append('. . . .')
dots_list[6].append('*')


for i in range(len(dots_list)):
    for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
        print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
'''



x = 0 # represents left and right direction in pd -- adding goes right, subtracting goes left
y = 0 # represents up and down direction in pd -- adding goes down, subtracting goes up
lower_bound = 1 #used as lower bound in dice selection
upper_bound = 4 #used as upper bound in dice selection
move_counter = 0 #used to count the total number of moves made in game

#print("Starting position: ",pd[y][x])  # The starting position used for debugging
start_position = pd[y][x] # The starting point of the game [y][x] up/down y, left/right x


# ----  loop begin ----
print('begin loop')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
while any(len(m) < 2 for m in dots_list):
    random_roll = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound) # Randomly selects a number from 1 to 4 to be used as fair die roll
    if random_roll == 1:
        print("Upper left Random Roll: " ,random_roll)
    elif random_roll == 2:
        print("Upper left Random Roll: ", random_roll)
    elif random_roll == 3:
        print("Upper left Random Roll: ", random_roll)
    else:
        print("Upper left Random Roll: ", random_roll)


#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    if random_roll == 1  and (pd[y][x]) != 2 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 4 and (pd[y][x]) != 11 and (pd[y][x]) != 16:
#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------

        print('upper left x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        if pd[y][x] == 1 or pd[y][x] == 2 or pd[y][x] == 4 or pd[y][x] == 7 or pd[y][x] == 11 or pd[y][x] == 16:
            print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
            dots_list[pd[y][x]].append('.')
            move_counter += 1
        else:
            new_pos = pd[y-1][x-1]
            y-=1
            x-=1
            #print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
            print('upper left new pos: ' , new_pos)
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
            start_position = new_pos
           # print('st pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position].append('.')


            move_counter += 1
#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    elif random_roll == 2  and (pd[y][x]) != 3 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 6 and (pd[y][x]) != 10 and (pd[y][x]) != 15 and (pd[y][x]) != 21:
    # --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
        print('upper right x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        print()


        if pd[y][x] == 1:
         print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
         print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
         dots_list[0].append('.')
         move_counter += 1
        else:
            new_pos = pd[y][x]
            y-=1
            x+=1
            print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
            print('upper right new pos: ' , new_pos)
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
            start_position = new_pos
            #print('st pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position].append('.')

            move_counter += 1


#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    elif random_roll == 3 and (pd[y][x]) != 16 and (pd[y][x]) != 17 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 18 and (pd[y][x]) != 19 and (pd[y][x]) != 20 and (pd[y][x]) != 21 \
             and (pd[y][x]) != 6 and (pd[y][x]) != 10 and (pd[y][x]) !=15   :
# --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
        print('down left x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        x+1
        new_pos = pd[y+1][x]
        x-=1
        #y+=1
        print('x: ', x,  'y:' , y)
        print('down left new pos: ' , new_pos)
        start_position = new_pos
        #print('start_position: ', start_position)
        print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
        dots_list[start_position-1].append('.')

        move_counter += 1

#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    elif random_roll == 4 and (pd[y][x]) != 16 and (pd[y][x]) != 17 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 18 and (pd[y][x]) != 19 and (pd[y][x]) != 20 and (pd[y][x]) != 21 :
# --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
        print('down right x: ', x, 'y:', y)

        new_pos = pd[y+1][x+1]
        x+=1
        y+=1

        print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        print('down right new pos: ' , new_pos)
        print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
        start_position = new_pos
        #print('st pos', start_position)
        dots_list[start_position-1].append('.')
        move_counter += 1

    else:
        #print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased:: rr: ' , random_roll)
        start_position = pd[y][x]
        #print('st pos', start_position)
        dots_list[start_position-1].append('.')
        move_counter += 1



# ---- loop end ----

# ---- Results printing ----
print('Move_counter:' ,move_counter)
for i in range(len(dots_list)):
    for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
        print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the game? What's a node?

Comment: So the logic is: each number in the pyramid represents a node. Starting from the number 1 roll a four-sided die with directions UL, UR, DL, DR which stand for up left, down right respectively. The object is to have the dice roll (randomly) and based on the number rolled go in that direction so long as there is another node to travel to. #5 can go UL, UR, DL, and DR,  which are 2,3,8,9 respectively I am getting out of bounds errors when trying to traverse the entire pyramid.  Visited nodes are marked with a dot and the game ends once every node has at least one dot.

Answer (score 0):

I did not debug your code, but trying to write a different one. I hope you can get an hint for finding out what is causing the error.

Here is the code I came out, please check the method `is_node(pos, height)`, I guess the answer could be there:

```
import random

def build_a_pyramid_of(n):
  res, tmp = [], []
  for i in range(n+1):
    tmp.append(i)
    if len(tmp) > len(res[:-1]):
      res.append(tmp)
      tmp = []
  return res[1:]

def nodes(pyramid):
  nodes = []
  for line in pyramid: nodes.extend(line)
  return nodes

def get_a_move():
  moves = [(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)] # change the moves as you will
  return random.choice(moves)

def is_node(pos, height):
  x, y  = pos[0], pos[1]
  if y >= 0 and y <= x and x <= height: return True
  else: return False

def next_pos_from(pos, height):
  try_pos = (0,0)
  while True:
    move = get_a_move()
    try_pos = (pos[0] + move[0], pos[1] + move[1])
    if is_node(try_pos, height): break
  return try_pos

# initialize
pyramid = build_a_pyramid_of(21)
nodes = nodes(pyramid)
heigth = len(pyramid)-1 # to just pass the heigh, not all the pyramid

# to visualize the pyramyd and nodes
for e in pyramid: print(e)
print('-'*20)
print(nodes)
print('-'*20)

# loop to transverse the pramyd
pos=(0,0)
while len(nodes) > 0:
  node = pyramid[pos[0]][pos[1]]
  if node in nodes: nodes.remove(node)
  old_pos = pos
  pos = next_pos_from(pos, heigth)
  print(old_pos, "->", pos, node, nodes) # to visuzlize the proces

print(nodes) #=> should return empty list
```

Comment: From reading through your code, It has to do with bounds checking. I made some changes to my code and the bounds are still an issue. I think this is one of the situations where I know the change to make, I just don't know where to make the changes haha. Thanks.

Comment: I'd add a check just after the `random_roll`, to confirm that the next position has valid indexes. If false, roll again. If true, go on with the program.